# redirect to iphone/blackberry compatible design

Tags: asp-classic

I created an iPhone/Blackberry compatible design for a website.  If the website is example.com, the iPhone/Blackberry compatible design is at example.com/m.

How do I detect iPhone/Blackberry users and make sure the website redirects them to the compatible design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to go with a UA detection script/library. One I found for ASP is here:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-asp

If the script does not offer the flexibility you want or is too complex for your needs, `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")` will return a user agent string that looks like this:

`BlackBerry9000/4.6.0.167 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/102`

In my experience, all BlackBerry browsers include "BlackBerry" in the UA string, and all iPhones include "iPhone" in the UA string, so you can run simple string manipulation on that. I'm a PHP man, so I can't help you write something off the top of my head, but if you need a sample code, post a comment and I or someone will get one out to you.

Comment: Thank you so much, HTTP_USER_AGENT should do it.